# How to dynamically add Id to a Textbox and retrive it in code behind in webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am building an e-commerce website in ASP Webforms. I am displaying product list  as listview which fetches data from SQL Serer. I have a textbox in the item template of the listview where a user can enter the quantity for the product. I want to set ID dynamically to the Control ID so I can retrieve the qty in code behind.

**bio.aspx**

```
 <ItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">
                <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' ID ="ImageLable" runat="server" CssClass="productImage" />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Product_NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[Product Name]") %>' />
                <br />Price:
                <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />
                <br />
                 <asp:TextBox ID='TextBox1' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </br>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonClick" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' OnClick="ButtonClick_Click"/>
            </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**bio.cs**

```
protected void ButtonClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    string buttonId = button.CommandArgument.ToString();
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(buttonId);
    String connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2016_675_z1787626ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        String command = "Insert into Cart (ProductId,ProductQty,UserId) Values(@ProductId,@ProductQ,1)";
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductQ", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    Response.Redirect("cart.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use Button Control's ***Command Event*** *(not click event)*, so that you can retrieve ***CommandArgument***.

For example,

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnCommand="AddToCartButton_Command" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' ID="AddToCartButton" 
    Text="Add To Cart"/>

protected void AddToCartButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    // Sibling textbox 
    var parent = (sender as Button).Parent;
    var textbox = parent.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
}
```

Comment: I want to add a textbox to enter quantity for each product list so when i click addToCart button , the Id along with the Product Quantity need to be updated to the database

Comment: But only the first product has the Id "TextBox1". I have nearly 20 products thats getting displayed through listview

Comment: It should not matter if you have 20 or 200 rows; you do not need to worry about that - ***naming container*** makes sure that textboxes inside each row has unique name.

Comment: Well when i tried your code I am getting `Object must implement IConvertible`